# Global Keyboard Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to capture key down events from the MainWindow, but I have a treeview which currently has focus is grabbing them before they reach my other class.  The TreeView is hooked into the PreviewKeyDown event and does some processing to ignore certain keystrokes.  I was hoping by hooking into the main window it would ignore that preview mouse down event.  Any thoughts on how to bypass the preview mouse down?

Comment: Why do you use Preview*Mouse*Down to ignore *keystrokes*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a window hook.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx) MSDN article for details.  [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) article has a mouse hook example.